# How to wrap long text inside column?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to wrap long text inside column in the gridview but it doesn't work the text always go outside the column or with the code below it extended the column width, but I need the text to be wrapped inside the column with specific width

```
<style type="text/css">  
    .WrapText {  
        width: 50%;  
        word-break: break-all;  
    }  
</style>
<div class="WrapText">  
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>  
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" Width="50px">  
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />  
            <Columns>  
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="req_id">  
                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />  
                    <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />  
                </asp:BoundField>  
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LastName" DataField="user_full_name_ar">  
                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />  
                    <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />  
                </asp:BoundField>  
            </Columns>  
        </asp:GridView>  
        </div>
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this seems more likely to be a CSS question.

Comment: Maybe `.WrapText td { word-break: break-all; }`

Comment: @VDWWD thanks for the replay but it still doesn't wrap text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, it wasn't wrapping text because of the table that has large width and it was inside the same div as the gridview.

my fault that I forgot to include table code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this css

.WrapText
 {
word-break:break-all
word-wrap:break-word;
}

Comment: Dhamejani thanks for the replay but it still doesn't wrap text –

Comment: <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="req_id" ItemStyle-Wrap="True">